# Xcode Realm - Undefined symbols std::bad_alloc

Tags: xcode, realm, carthage

Cartfile:

```
github "realm/realm-cocoa" ~> 10.20.0
```

Carthage version:

```
0.38.0
```

Installing by:

```
carthage update --use-xcframeworks --platform iOS --verbose
```

Installing Realm gives this error on build:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()", referenced from:
   realm::keychain::(anonymous namespace)::set_key(std::__1::vector<char, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, __CFString const*, __CFString const*) in Realm(keychain_helper.o)
   realm::keychain::(anonymous namespace)::build_search_dictionary(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, realm::util::Optional<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >) in Realm(keychain_helper.o)
```

Answer (score 1):

These undefined symbols are from other libraries. Including `libc++.tbl` and `libz.tbl` solved the issue.

Comment: Is this actually an answer or are you just saying the issue was resolved by some other means?

Comment: It is the answer